# Expected an Idented block

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to run this in pyspark shell but it returns an error "expected and indented block".

```
for c_name in df_format_1.columns:
        df_format_1 = df_format_1(c_name, trim(F.col(c_name)))
```

I searched and saw that this error occurs when `for` loop hasn't got a body, but the only thing I want to do is to trim all the columns in a df.

Comment: You need to indent the second line. In the pyspark shell, after typing the first line, hit enter, press space four times, and type the second line. Note that your second line has a syntax error though

Comment: @mck Thanks for your quick response. I run it and you were right. It says that df is not callable.

Comment: you probably meant df_format_1.withColumn(c_name, trim(F.col(c_name)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close the post:

[Here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) is the documentation regarding indentation error.

```
for c_name in df_format_1.columns:
    df_format_1.withColumn(c_name, trim(F.col(c_name)))
```